# Why does Ubuntu either detect the size of hosting OS window or not?

Tags: virtualbox, display

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.4 under Oracle Virtual Box 4.3.12 and found that Ubuntu sometimes detects the size of hosting windows and sometimes not.

I want it always detects.

How to ensure this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having display troubles in the Virtual Machine, the first step should always be to try installing Guest Additions. See [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm)